# Hover change color of border uneven

Tags: html, css

I have gotten the colour to change by hovering the mouse over the span but for some reason one of the borders has a singular segment that changes to the wrong colour.

```css
.features article .icon:after {
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: solid 2px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7em;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3.5em 0 0 -3.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 7em;
}

.features article .icon:hover:after {
  transition: ease-out;
  border-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section -->
<section>
  <div class="features">
    <article>
      <span><a href="#fp" class="icon solid fa-fire" id="firelogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Fire Relief</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Fire Relief' charity selected will provide money to a choice fire relief charity fund. The money donated to fire relief funds could set up a 'disaster relief fund' which can provide support to families of firefighters who've
          died and people in communities impacted by the fires.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#cp" class="icon solid fa-ribbon" id="cancerlogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Cancer Support</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Cancer Support' charity selected will provide money to a choice cancer support fund. The fund money goes to researcher salaries , consumables and instrumentation. There have been progressively improving outcomes due to the
          funding provided through charity - more people surviving after diagnosis.</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#ap" class="icon solid fa-dna" id="aidslogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Aids Research</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Aids Research' charity selected will provide money to a choice aids research fund. Funding for Aids services and activities is spread across multiple federal departments, including Health and Human Services (HHS), Housing and
          Urban Development (HUD), Justice, Veterans Affairs (VA), and Defense</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#wp" class="icon solid fa-water" id="waterlogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Water Aid</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Water Aid' charity selected will provide money to a choice water aid fund. The funding works to enabale people to transform their lives with safe water, decent toilets and good hygiene in developing countries and war stricken
          areas
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is what it looks like while it hovers over:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAe5N.png)

And this is what is looks like without hover:[image]

If you need any more information just let me know

Comment: It's quite normal in this code snippet.

Comment: you should add only relevant minimal code. Anyway, looks like it works

Comment: @Omri: while the edit was mostly good, please remember that English UK spelling is considered to be as equally correct as English US here on Stack Overflow. In this case it seems OP was using the English UK spelling, so I edited it back to his preference.

Comment: I have added an example of the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try `border-bottom-color:#f9666a;`;

```css
.features article .icon:after {
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: solid 2px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7em;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3.5em 0 0 -3.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 7em;
}

.features article .icon:hover:after {
  transition: ease-out;
  border-color: #39befc;
  border-bottom-color:#f9666a;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section -->
<section>
  <div class="features">
    <article>
      <span><a href="#fp" class="icon solid fa-fire" id="firelogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Fire Relief</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Fire Relief' charity selected will provide money to a choice fire relief charity fund. The money donated to fire relief funds could set up a 'disaster relief fund' which can provide support to families of firefighters who've
          died and people in communities impacted by the fires.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#cp" class="icon solid fa-ribbon" id="cancerlogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Cancer Support</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Cancer Support' charity selected will provide money to a choice cancer support fund. The fund money goes to researcher salaries , consumables and instrumentation. There have been progressively improving outcomes due to the
          funding provided through charity - more people surviving after diagnosis.</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#ap" class="icon solid fa-dna" id="aidslogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Aids Research</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Aids Research' charity selected will provide money to a choice aids research fund. Funding for Aids services and activities is spread across multiple federal departments, including Health and Human Services (HHS), Housing and
          Urban Development (HUD), Justice, Veterans Affairs (VA), and Defense</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <span><a href="#wp" class="icon solid fa-water" id="waterlogo"></a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Water Aid</h3>
        <p>Purchases with the 'Water Aid' charity selected will provide money to a choice water aid fund. The funding works to enabale people to transform their lives with safe water, decent toilets and good hygiene in developing countries and war stricken
          areas
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: chirs, if this answer solves your problem, try upvoting it

Comment: I tried and it did change the faulty colour but I have since discovered that is most likely picking up the wrong inherit colour.

Comment: Are you want like this @Chris de Wet ? I updated answer. If no, please attach first apprearence color and hover color in question.

Comment: I'll add that now @RubixOverflow. The issue with using a set colour rather than inherent is that i have multiple ones that require different colours but for some reason this one is not working.

Comment: There is no `inherent` in **border-color** [visit this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-border-color)